# MySQL UPDATE with a JOIN to a subselect

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table called `sagepaydirect__transactions` which I am updating with a migration to set its `response` field to the `response` field of the table called `sagepaydirect__responses`.

The two tenuously link via a table named `sagepaydirect__requests` on the last 4 digits of the _ separated string in the field `vendor_tx_code`.

The problem is that `sagepaydirect__requests` will have multiple rows when joined to `sagepaydirect__transactions`. What I want to do is do the JOIN such that the UPDATE takes the value from the row in `sagepaydirect__transactions` whose ID is numerically higher.

This is my attempt at the query but the complaint is that `t.id` does not exist.

```
UPDATE sagepaydirect__transactions t
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM sagepaydirect__requests rq
        WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(rq.vendor_tx_code, '_', -1) = t.id
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 1
) rq_table
ON t.id = SUBSTRING_INDEX(rq_table.vendor_tx_code, '_', -1)
INNER JOIN sagepaydirect__responses rs
ON rq.id = rs.request_id
SET t.response = rs.status_detail
```

Comment: You have the same condition in the join's `ON` clause. It ought to work if you just remove the `WHERE` condition from the subquery, where it is redundant and incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use a correlated subquery in the `from` clause.  That won't work.  The following uses aggregation to get the maximum `id`, and then continues with the `join`s.

```
UPDATE sagepaydirect__transactions t INNER JOIN
       (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(rq.vendor_tx_code, '_', -1) as val, max(id) as maxid
        FROM sagepaydirect__requests rq
        WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(rq.vendor_tx_code, '_', -1) = t.id
        group by id SUBSTRING_INDEX(rq.vendor_tx_code, '_', -1)
      ) rq
      ON t.id = rq.val INNER JOIN
      sagepaydirect__responses rs
      ON rq.id = rs.request_id
    SET t.response = rs.status_detail;
```

Comment: What about this 1) Get all what you want in Select Statement (Into one Temp Table)  2) Do simple update statement relating to temp table.

Comment: @Maverick . . . Of course, using temporary tables is another approach, but that is not necessary for this query.  If the data is being modified while the process is running, multiple steps introduce race conditions and additional programming overhead to deal with them.

Comment: Yess Even I agree.. Make use of Stored Procedures and Temporary table so simplify complex conditional updates